# Wireless Network Question?

Tags: wireless-networking

Will the D-Link - Xtreme N Wireless-N Gigabit Router work with my AR5009 802.11 a/g/n WiFi Adapter?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The D-Link Xtreme N™ Gigabit Router
>   (DIR-655) is a 802.11n compliant
>   device that delivers up to 14x faster
>   speeds* and 6x farther range* than
>   802.11g while staying backward compatible with 802.11g devices.

Your adapter supports both 802.11n and 802.11g protocol versions. So **it will work**.

Comment: Yes. Sorry, that was a typo.

Answer (score 0):

FYI this isn't a dual band router.  If you have g and n devices connecting to this router, all devices will connect at 802.11g if set to "mixed mode g/n"